# Обработка запроса Wallet One

Tags: php, веб-программирование

В [документации](https://www.walletone.com/ru/merchant/documentation/) к Wallet One API написано, что при обработке ответа об оплате в случае успеха нужно вернуть строку `WMI_RESULT=OK`. Я именно так и делаю, но запрос приходит снова и снова. Вот URL: http://ipkit.ru/post.php

Answer (score 1):

достаточно отправить`echo WMI_RESULT=OK;`

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?